# Qt boost serialize compile errors on simple implementation

Tags: boost, g++

Platform specifics:
Fedora 21 
g++ 4.9.2-6

Here's the error ....

```
$ g++ -c kabi-serial.cpp -lboost_serialization
kabi-serial.cpp: In function ‘void boost::serialization::kb_write_list()’:
kabi-serial.cpp:41:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘oa’
   serialize oa(ofs);

kabi-serial.cpp:41:20: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
   serialize oa(ofs);
                ^
kabi-serial.cpp:42:3: error: ‘oa’ was not declared in this scope
   oa << ql;
```

And here's the kabi-serial.cpp source ...

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

class Cqnodelist
{
public:
     friend class boost::serialization::access;
     Cqnodelist(){}
     std::vector<int>qnodelist;

     template<class Archive>
     void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
     {
         ar & qnodelist;
     }
 };

 void kb_write_list ()
 {
     Cqnodelist ql;

     ofstream ofs("kabi-list.dat");
     {
         serialize oa(ofs);
         oa << ql;
     }
 }
 }
 }
```

I based the source code on the simplest of the serialization examples, except using the serialization of the stl vector object.

I'm sure it's simple, but what am I missing?

Comment: What is `serialize` in `serialize oa(ofs);`? You create object of type `serialize`, but I don't see this type definition.

Comment: It's part of the boost serialization namespace. It coul be expressed as follows ...

  boost::serialization::access::serialize oa(ofs);

Evokes the same error, though.

Answer (score 1):

To use `ofstream` you need to include `<fstream>`.

`ofstream` is in the namespace `std`: `std::ofstream`.

You don't need to put your code inside `boost::serialization` namespace (except case when you implement external to class `serialize()` function).

Adding `serialize` method implements way of loading and saving object attributes.
To actually store or load data you need to select storage — archive in Boost.Serialization terminology.

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <fstream> // required for std::ofstream

class Cqnodelist
{
public:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    Cqnodelist(){}
    std::vector<int>qnodelist;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & qnodelist;
    }
};

void kb_write_list ()
{
    Cqnodelist ql;

    // fill object with data
    ql.qnodelist.push_back(1);
    ql.qnodelist.push_back(2);
    ql.qnodelist.push_back(3);

    // See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html
    // for reference

    // save data to archive
    {
       // open file that will contain serialized data
       std::ofstream ofs("kabi-list.dat");

       // create archive on top of opened file
       boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
       // write class instance to archive
       oa << ql;
    }

    // to load object later open file, create input archive on top of opened
    // file and load object state
    {
       Cqnodelist new_ql;

       // create and open an archive for input
       std::ifstream ifs("kabi-list.dat");
       boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
       // read class state from archive
       ia >> new_ql;
    }
}

int main()
{
    kb_write_list();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already had #include <fstream>, but forgot to show it in my code sample above. The line that was killing me was this one...
serialize oa(ofs);
... which should have been ...
text_oarchive oa(ofs);

Howver, I have a new question. Why is the compiler okay with ...
std::vector<int>qnodelist;
... but throws an error for ...
std::vector<int *>qnodelist;
The error is  ...
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118: error: request for member 'serialize' in 't', which is of non-class type 'int'
         t.serialize(ar, file_version);

Comment: @TonyCamuso, why do you need to store `int *`? I think you need to specify external serialization method for `int` type, but I don't think that storing `int *` is what you want.

Comment: Well, it was just an exercise, a test. I was trying to store a compound data type using a pointer (vector<qnode *>. What I did not understand was that all the data types contained by that data type must also have serialize methods.